# Mouse buttons become unresponsive

Tags: mouse

For the past couple of days, I have noticed that my mouse buttons will stop working and not allow me to click on anything. I have found that anytime I try to click on a separate window, Applications, or settings in the task bar, the buttons stop working. If I Alt + Tab, or Windows key + A (on a Windows keyboard), my mouse will begin working again until the next time I click on any of the aforementioned items. My keyboard seems to work even when the mouse buttons do not.

I am new to elementary, just installing it about 3 weeks ago, and I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting. Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: I have very much the same problem - posted just before you. I've searched for hours but can't seem to get to the bottom of it. See my thread for what I've found so far though, I'm just about to update it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix to this problem: I performed 3 updates just before noticing these issues. I removed each and tested, and no longer experience the issue. I was unable to pinpoint if it was just one of the upgrades or a combination of them together. The updates were Intel-microcode 3.20170707.1, nvidia-304, and nvidia-340. Please keep in mind that I had to reboot before I saw the fix.